# sql - exclude result from result set where a table value equals something

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on a small application that allows me to track my work priorities based on certain criteria such as company level, moneys paid, project status etc..

I have a page that shows me all the companies and their breakdowns based on the categories(as described above).

As an example, to pull all my general todos, i do something like:

```
$pullAllGeneralTodosDone = "SELECT * FROM to_dos WHERE to_do_is_for = '$login_usrname' AND is_to_do_complete = 'no' AND company_to_do = 'COMPANY NAME HERE' ORDER BY company_to_do ASC;";
```

With the above, say that i have a general todos for 10 companies in the database, then this pulls all ten.

Now what i would like to do is, to pull the same data except that now, i want to exclude any value returned that includes a particular company name.

So for example, if i have a general todos for 10 companies, and one of those companies is called "COMPANY A", then i want the query above to EXCLUDE COMPANY A resulting in 9 entries shown on my page.

I was going to do some hackery like 
[pseudo code]

```
<?php

if ( $row['company_to_do'] == 'COMPANY A' ) { 

?>

code here with some css class that gets hidden because its COMPANY A which i dont want to see.

<?php } ?>
```

But this is too messy...
I KNOW it can be done in sql and ive been looking around and found NOT IN and NOT EXIST

But it just doesnt work, i have a mess...

EDIT***

these are the two ways ive tried as per the replies below, and although i dont get any errors, the "COMPANY A" still shows alongside the rest of the information.

ive tried:

```
$pullAllGeneralTodosDone = "SELECT * FROM to_dos WHERE to_do_is_for = '$login_usrname' AND is_to_do_complete = 'no' AND company_to_do = 'GENERAL TO-DO' AND  company_to_do <> 'COMPANY A' ORDER BY company_to_do ASC;”;
```

and

```
$pullAllGeneralTodosDone = "SELECT * FROM to_dos WHERE to_do_is_for = '$login_usrname' AND is_to_do_complete = 'no' AND company_to_do = 'GENERAL TO-DO' AND  company_to_do NOT IN ('COMPANY A') ORDER BY company_to_do ASC;”;
```

Any ideas as how i can merge a NOT IN / NOT EXIST with my query above?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the is not operator `<>`

```
SELECT pub_name,country,pub_city,estd   
FROM publisher   
WHERE country <>"USA";
```

This will pull all publishers not from the USA.

Comment: Hi Anthony. Ive gone in and put it in like this: //// $pullAllGeneralTodosDone = "SELECT * FROM to_dos WHERE to_do_is_for = '$login_usrname' AND is_to_do_complete = 'no' AND company_to_do = 'GENERAL TO-DO' AND  company_to_do <> 'COMPANY A' ORDER BY company_to_do ASC;"; \\\\ and it doesnt work. I dont get any errors or anything but COMPANY A still shows. Any thoughts? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure NOT IN is your answer, if you want conciseness.  The values, though, have to be concatenated and placed in parentheses:

```
$pullAllGeneralTodosDone = "SELECT * FROM to_dos WHERE to_do_is_for
= '$login_usrname' AND is_to_do_complete = 'no' AND company_to_do 
= 'COMPANY NAME HERE' AND  company_to_do NOT IN 
('COMPANY A','FOOBAR WIDGETS, LLC','MICROSOFT CORPORATION') 
ORDER BY company_to_do ASC;";
```

The problem being the concatenation and parens, and also that this can bog things down if you have large data sets or lots of exclusions.

Comment: Howdy there. I tried this and although i dont get any errors, it still doesnt work. Here is what i added. /// $pullAllGeneralTodosDone = "SELECT * FROM to_dos WHERE to_do_is_for = '$login_usrname' AND is_to_do_complete = 'no' AND company_to_do = 'GENERAL TO-DO' AND  company_to_do NOT IN ('COMPANY A') ORDER BY company_to_do ASC;"; \\\ . Again, it doesnt throw any errors but "COMPANY A" still shows. Any ideas?

Comment: Other than checking the docs for operator precedence (or just short-cutting that and trying some different parenthetical groupings), no; not without a sample dataset to test with, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

$pullAllGeneralTodosDone = "SELECT * FROM to_dos WHERE to_do_is_for = '".$login_usrname."' AND is_to_do_complete = 'no' AND company_to_do = 'GENERAL TO-DO' AND  company_to_do <> 'DIGITAL WHITE BOARD' ORDER BY company_to_do ASC;”;

Regards,
Tarun

Comment: You should use [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answer.